# How do I insert the auto-increment ID into a MySQL table using MySQL ODBC with ASP.Net/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, odbc, auto-increment

I am using MySQL ODBC to insert data into a MySQL table. The first column in the table is an ID that is of type int and auto increments. When I insert the data for the very first row, what should the value be for @ReqID, as shown below? Also, how do I ensure that subsequent executions are auto incrementing for the ID?

Here is the C#:

```
            string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString;
        using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO GraphicsRequest (RequestID, Graphic1Desc, Graphic2Desc, Graphic3Desc, ColorChart, Hex1, Hex2, Hex3, Hex4) VALUES (@reqID, @g1d, @g2d, @g3d, @colorChart, @hex1, @hex2, @hex3, @hex4)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reqID", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g1d", txtGraphic1Desc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g2d", txtGraphic2Desc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g3d", txtGraphic3Desc.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colorChart", ddlColorChart.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex1", lblColor1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex2", lblColor2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex3", lblColor3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex4", lblColor4.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You shouldn't need to insert data for an auto increment column.

Comment: @Monica...I agree with Kush

Comment: Am I supposed to instead replace '@reqID' with a question mark for the VALUES section?

Comment: @Monica...not sure about MySql, but in SQL Server, I just skip it

Comment: Additionally, you should install the MySQL Connection and use the MySQL specific objects instead of the generic OLEDB objects: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: @MarkKram, I tried using that but couldn't find much help for it.

Comment: @MonicaRice please see my answer regarding the use of the MySQL Connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you shouldn't supply the ID-field during an INSERT if you want to use the auto incrementing feature of the database itself.

So that would be in your case.

```
        string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString;
    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO GraphicsRequest (Graphic1Desc, Graphic2Desc, Graphic3Desc, ColorChart, Hex1, Hex2, Hex3, Hex4) VALUES (@g1d, @g2d, @g3d, @colorChart, @hex1, @hex2, @hex3, @hex4)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g1d", txtGraphic1Desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g2d", txtGraphic2Desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g3d", txtGraphic3Desc.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colorChart", ddlColorChart.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex1", lblColor1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex2", lblColor2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex3", lblColor3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex4", lblColor4.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

This way the database will INSERT a new row with the next available the ID for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other have answered your question, I would suggest that you use the MySQL Connector in your project instead of using OLEDB objects. [Download and install the MySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and then add a reference in your project to the MySQL.Data extension and then add the MySql.Data.MySqlClient using statement to your class and then update your code as follows:

```
string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString;
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     con.Open();
     using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand() 
     {
            cmd.Connection = con; //<-- It looks like you are missing this line in your code
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO GraphicsRequest (Graphic1Desc, Graphic2Desc, Graphic3Desc, ColorChart, Hex1, Hex2, Hex3, Hex4) VALUES (@g1d, @g2d, @g3d, @colorChart, @hex1, @hex2, @hex3, @hex4)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g1d", txtGraphic1Desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g2d", txtGraphic2Desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g3d", txtGraphic3Desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colorChart", ddlColorChart.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex1", lblColor1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex2", lblColor2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex3", lblColor3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hex4", lblColor4.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I have another question. Do I need to add the System DSN to my machine in order to connect to a remote MySQL server?

Comment: No, just create a a Connection String: string connString = string.Format(@"Provider=MySQLProv;Location={0};Data Source={1};USER ID={2};PASSWORD={3};option=3;port=3306;", ServerName, DatabaseName, LoginName, Password);

Comment: You are a <DEITY>send. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to use your existing connection string.

Answer (score 0):

probably this would solve the problem .

```
strong textcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
long id = com.LastInsertedId;
```